# Best way to convert azure logs date time into an excel date time

Tags: azure, entra-id, azure-web-apps, microsoft-excel

Hello when I export Azure logs to csv I get this datetime format that excel doesn't recognize as a valid date time format:

```
2022-10-19T12:05:58Z
```

Is this the best way to convert this to an excel datetime or is there something simpler?

```
=DATE(MID(A107,1,4),MID(A107,6,2),MID(A107,9,2)) + 
    TIME(MID(A107,12,2),MID(A107,15,2),MID(A107,18,2)) 
    - TIME(5,0,0) 
    + TIME(1,0,0)
```

This minus five hours is to convert it into Easter Standard Time and the plus one hours is to account for daylight savings time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Azure log dates are in UTC.  Take a look at:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36456115/excel-how-to-convert-utc-date-time

`=--SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND("Z",A1)-1),"T"," ")`

Comment: Just remove the Z, thank you!